# Cannot implicitly convert type.. Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-profile

I've googled this error and got a variety of results, none really working for my situation.

I currently have a CRUD (scaffold) for the Identity in Web Forms that will work as a user profile.

I have this

```
public IQueryable<WebApplication2.Models.MyAppUser> GetData()
{
    var currentUser = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
    return currentUser;
}
```

However I get this error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'WebApplication2.Models.MyAppUser' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

As I said I did some research. I believe it's because I am trying to return a var.. however I don't know how to properly handle this. I've tried creating a function that does it but that didn't work out for me either.

Please help.

**I am using Web forms (not MVC)**

Answer (score 1):

You are either using a wrong LINQ method, or a wrong method signature.

The `FirstOrDefault` method returns a single `MyAppUser`, not an `IQueryable<MyAppUser>`. You have two choices for fixing this:

- Replace `FirstOrDefault` call with `Take(1)` call

Here is how:

```
return _db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).Take(1);
```

- Change the method signature to return `MyAppUser` instead of `IQueryable<MyAppUser>`

Both fixes will get your code to compile. Picking one over the other depends on the use of the `GetData` method in your application.

Answer (score 0):

First: why return IQueryable<> you need only return one object

Second: cuurentUser in Entity obejct you should cast it to your domain model:

```
public WebApplication2.Models.MyAppUser GetData()
{
    var currentUser = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
    return currentUser ;
}
```

Or

```
public IQueryable<WebApplication2.Models.MyAppUser> GetData()
{
   return _db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);                       
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both you for the fast responses! I got it to work. The IQueryable came from the generated code from the scaffold. Without it I got an error.

Comment: You can add new method or instead of retutn single object return list